# Ordenação em Python de lista de dicionários por chave e valor em ordens distintas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, classificação, dicionário

Como ordenar uma lista de dicionários por exemplo:

```
nomes = [{'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome' 'alves'},{'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome' 'silva'}]
```

- Por ordem alfabética os nomes
- Por ordem inversa, os sobrenomes
  isto é: no sentido normal o nome e no sentido inverso o sobrenome

Comment: Você quer uma saída como: João Alves, João Silva ?

Comment: João Silva, João Alves. Nesse caso só tem um tipo de nome, mas queria que o desempate fosse pela ordem inversa do sobrenome, ou seja o contrario da ordem alfabetica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em python a ordenação de uma lista é **garantidamente estável**, ou seja, no caso de comparações iguais a ordem inicial dos elementos é preservada.

De posse desta informação o problema fica simples. Primeiro ordena-se reversamente pelo sobrenome, depois ordena-se diretamente pelo nome.

A seguir um exemplo de implementação do código:

```
nomes = [{'nome': 'marcelo', 'sobrenome': 'alves'},
        {'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome': 'tavares'},
        {'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome': 'alves'},
        {'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome': 'nogueira'},
        {'nome': 'joao', 'sobrenome': 'silva'},
        {'nome': 'barbara', 'sobrenome': 'wilson'},
        {'nome': 'antonio', 'sobrenome': 'silva'}]

nomes.sort(key = lambda i: i['sobrenome'], reverse = True)
nomes.sort(key = lambda i: i['nome'])

[print("{:10} {:10}".format(item['nome'], item['sobrenome'])) for item in nomes]
```